# import problem when just use the geometry library of jointjs

Tags: jointjs

this is a typescript supported simple create-react-app project, and i use VS code
i downloaded `geometry.d.ts` and `geometry.js`(which renamed from geometry.mjs)  into the project
then i try to import it like `import * as g from "../../shared/geometry";`
funny thing is, ts-check said i have type 2 `g`s to get inside the `g` namespace
but after compiled and run in browser, `g.g` is undefined
what happed here?  how to get rid of the second `g` ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK,finally,
I placed the .d.ts filne to a separate folder
I added  a reference comment  `/// <reference path="../../types/geometry.d.ts" />` in the head of geometry.js file
in the end of it, change the code like this

```
// exports.Curve = Curve;
// exports.Ellipse = Ellipse;
// exports.Line = Line;
// exports.Path = Path;
// exports.Point = Point;
// exports.Polyline = Polyline;
// exports.Rect = Rect;
// exports.bezier = bezier;
// exports.ellipse = ellipse;
// exports.line = line;
// exports.normalizeAngle = normalizeAngle;
// exports.point = point;
// exports.random = random;
// exports.rect = rect;
// exports.scale = scale;
// exports.snapToGrid = snapToGrid;
// exports.toDeg = toDeg;
// exports.toRad = toRad;

export {
    Curve,
    Ellipse,
    Line,
    Path,
    Point,
    Polyline,
    Rect,
    bezier,
    ellipse,
    line,
    normalizeAngle,
    point,
    random,
    rect,
    scale,
    snapToGrid,
    toDeg,
    toRad
};
```

then import g like `import * as g from "../shared/geometry";`
everthing looks fine now